# How to define the value type for iterator which points to an element in another container in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

The purpose I want to achieve is that:
I have an `unordered_map<int, list<int>::iterator> mp` and a `list<int> lst`. How can I store the iterator of an element in `lst`. And later, by using the iterators in map, I can manipulate (e.g.,erase) the element in the list. (Assume free of iterator invalidation problem)
The following snippet won't work:

```cpp
unordered_map<int, list<int>::const_iterator> mp;
list<int> lst;
lst.push_back(1);
mp[1]=lst.crbegin(); //error here
lst.erase(mp[1]);
...
```

I have also tried to store raw pointers, but I was not able to erase an element in the list by using a raw pointer. I was wondering what is the best way to fulfill my purpose.

Comment: Forward and reverse iterators are different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the wrong kind of iterator into the `unordered_map`:

```
unordered_map<int, list<int>::const_iterator> mp;
// ...
mp[1] = lst.crbegin();  // error, const reverse iterator
mp[1] = lst.cbegin();   // ok
```

If you want the value type of the `unordered_map` to contain reverse iterators, you need to specify that:

```
unordered_map<int, list<int>::const_reverse_iterator> mp;
// ...
mp[1] = lst.cbegin();    // error, const forward iterator
mp[1] = lst.crbegin();   // ok
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ors5dG).

---

It seems that you are trying to add a reverse iterator, because you want to conveniently get an iterator to the last element in the list. You can do that with:

```
mp[1] = std::prev(lst.cend(), 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see the reason now. However, if I use `const_iterator` type in map. How can I add the *last* element's iterator in the list to the map. The issue is that: if I use `const_reverse_iterator` as value type, I am not able to call `lst.erase(mp[1])`

Comment: @kz28 `std::next(lst.cend(),-1)` should do it, so you don't need reverse iterators at all. And the list had better not be empty.

Comment: @kz28 Edited the answer to show alternatives to using reverse iterators.